# How to find a "burst quality" in a spectrogram?

Tags: phonetics, praat, affricates, plosives

[image]

What is the "burst quality" in a spectrogram? So for the example I provided from praat what would be the burst quality for the affricate shown below? Is it similar to a plosive?

Comment: It would help if you'd clarify where you came across the term "burst quality", and in what context.